# In Swift how to have a global tint color except in one place?

Tags: swift, uiappearance, tintcolor

In my app I have a global tint color that I set in the app delegate like this and it works fine. I get that tint color everywhere.

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = globalTintColor
```

I have a table view in a particular view controller where I want the checkmarks (accessoryType) to be a different color.

I tried this.

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = globalTintColor
UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyViewController.self]).tintColor = .red
```

But that had no effect. I changed the order and that also had no effect. If I comment out the UIView appearance code I get closer to what I want.

```
// UIView.appearance().tintColor = globalTintColor
UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyViewController.self]).tintColor = .red
```

With this I get the default blue tint everywhere *except* in instances of MyViewController where checkmarks are red.

What am I missing? How do I have a global tint color except in one particular place?

Comment: I would avoid using the Appearance Proxy and rather subclass UIView / UIViewController, because it's hard to debug.